# Why is the order of haystack and needle inconsistent in PHP functions in_array and strpos?

Tags: php, api-design, language-design

The order of parameters `haystack` and `needle` in these 2 very core PHP functions is not consistent:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php (needle, haystack)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php (haystack, needle)

Why is this the case?

Comment: I don't think these type of questions (language design choices) are allowed here. I however can't find the belonging meta post for it. It's a similar question I once asked why does Swift use `func` instead of `function`

Comment: In its early stages the language has grown organically, its design has not been carefully planned. The author added functions based on their immediate needs. `strpos()` (and many other string functions) are wrappers of the standard C library functions with the name name, consequently they have the same arguments as the C functions they wrap.

Comment: Rasmus wasn't trying to write a language that would become even a fraction of a percent as popular as PHP has. He's very open about the inconsistencies - in my mind, it's ultimately everyone else's fault for adopting the language in spite of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Needle/Haystack in PHP

They are actually not inconsistent like many think. You have partly discovered the consistency:

- All string functions are (haystack, needle)
- All array functions are (needle, haystack)

Rasmus Lerdorf (the creator of PHP) states this in a talk in 2019 around 25 minutes in:

**25 Years of PHP - phpday 2019**

https://youtu.be/iGOAQli7tGc?t=1485

### Inconsistencies in PHP

At 16:45, he has a slide titled "What was he thinking?" and he addresses "naming inconsistencies". (needle/haystack issue is just one of them)

https://youtu.be/iGOAQli7tGc?t=1005

In this talk he also explains that his design decisions for PHP are almost all based on the idea that PHP is a "wrapper for underlying C libraries", and has kept the parameters in the same order as the underlying code.

Comment: Well not entirely true. Functions like str_replace(find,replace,string,count) are string functions which also follow the needle / haystack principle (even though the params are not called like that). And they do have the needle in front and the haystack in the end. So this definitely does not help remembering the order of all the various string functions.
And there are also array functions like array_keys that turn around these params in an unintuitive way. As mentioned here https://gist.github.com/salathe/1672543